# Select first suggestion from Typeahead.js when hit Enter key in the field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I want to select first available suggestion from Typeahead.js suggestion items, when I hit Enter key while I'm focused on that field.

I got this code by now:

```
$('#cities-prefetch .typeahead').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var value = $('input:text#city').typeahead('val');
    }
});
```

But that only fetches the current selected value from with in the field itself.

Please help!

Comment: [typeahead.js bug #32](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/32) - Option for Automatic selection of the first item in the typeahead resultset

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could trigger a `click` on the first suggestion if the Enter key is pressed

```
$('#cities-prefetch .typeahead').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $(".tt-suggestion:first-child", this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

See this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d44e6ks/1/)**

Comment: it's now .twitter-typeahead not .typeahead.  for those who need to use this.

Comment: If your typeahead is inside a form, it submitted the form instead of doing the keyup event. My solution was to trigger the click on form submit.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It just skips to the next input

Comment: I had to use a class/id higher up on the page to envoke the keyup function. I used the Bootstrap .row class - `$('.row').on('keyup', function(e) {`. Might help someone..

Answer (score 3):

this worked in my case.

```
$('[id$=_form]').on('keydown', '.twitter-typeahead #input_id', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tt-selectable').first().click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In typeahead.js 0.11.1 this seems to do the trick for me.

```
$(element).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //find the selectable item under the input, if any:
        var selectables = $(element).siblings(".tt-menu").find(".tt-selectable");
        if (selectables.length > 0){
             $(selectables[0]).trigger('click');    
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectables = $(element).siblings(".tt-dropdown-menu").find(".tt-suggestion");
    if (selectables.length > 0) {
      $(selectables[0]).trigger('click');
    } else {
        $(butto_element).trigger('click');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoselect` – If `true`, the typeahead will autoselect the first suggestion when the Enter key has been pressed. Defaults to `false`.
[refrence](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/commit/744e6fe4151937b39cd2d1723c21309bbcfaf89e)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/commit/744e6fe4151937b39cd2d1723c21309bbcfaf89e#commitcomment-21942892